# Finding the sum of combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem: 
$$$$
Finding the sum of combinatorics
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{{}_{n}C_{k}(-1)^k}{n+k+1}=? ~~~~~~~~~~~~
\left({}_{n}C_{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution,it's mainly manipulation of the function $(1+x)^n$
$$(1-x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n} C_kx^k(-1)^k$$
$$(x)^n(1-x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k C_kx^{n+k}$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k C_k\frac1{n+k+1}=\int_0^1x^n(1-x)^ndx=\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}$$
Note : To solve the integral, integrate by parts to get a reduction formula.

Comment: Check the value at n=1 . It is equal to $(1/6)$ but according to your formula it is $(1/2)$ @IshanBanerjee

Comment: Thanks. I made a mistake in evaluating the integral. I reduced it one fewer than I needed to

Comment: You are welcome m8....

Comment: How did you integrate the function, by the way?

Comment: I will be updating soon.....

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle (1-x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}x^k$

Multiplying with $x^n$ on both sides we get $\displaystyle x^n(1-x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}x^{(n+k)}$

Integrating from 0 to 1 on both sides we have ,

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}x^n(1-x)^n d x=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}x^{(n+k)} d x$

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}x^n(1-x)^n d x=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{n+k+1}\binom{n}{k}  $

$\Rightarrow \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{n+k+1}\binom{n}{k}=\int_{0}^{1}x^n(1-x)^n d x =\frac{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(2n+2)}=\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}$